# K.<v> notation in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, sage

In one [example of Sage math](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/matrix_gps/finitely_generated.html#sage.groups.matrix_gps.finitely_generated.FinitelyGeneratedMatrixGroup_gap.molien_series) (search for `octahedral`) there is this line:

```
K.<v> = sage.groups.matrix_gps.finitely_generated.CyclotomicField(10)
```

What does this `.<v>` do?

Comment: Can you link to the example? That doesn't look like anything Python I'm familiar with.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that would be a SyntaxError in any version Python.

Comment: "*SageMath is a free open-source mathematics software system [...]. Access their combined power through a common, Python-based language*" - i.e. not bare Python directly.

Comment: I have never even heard of this However 2 mins of reading the documentation describes this as `We can specify a different generator name as follows`. so `v` would be the generator name returned by `k.gen()`. I would suggest to read the documentation.

Comment: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/sage/repl/preparse.html#sage.repl.preparse.preparse_generators looks relevant.

Comment: Oh, I get it! You are not supposed to start up `python2` and `import sage` but rather start `sage`; at least not for this example. Okay, then it is no surprise that there is special syntax.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: Thanks for the pointer. It did not occur to me that Sage might have a custom interpreter. Therefore I thought this was some Python syntax I never saw before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SageMath code is not Python, albeit very similar. The syntax

```
A.<b> = C(d, e, f)
```

in SageMath is roughly equivalent to the following Python code

```
A = C(d, e, f, names=('b',))
b = A.gen()
```

I.e., first the parent ring `A` is created, with generator named `'b'`, then a variable `b` is initialized to the generator of `A`.

You can see what any SageMath statement is translated to using the function `preparse()`:

```
sage: preparse('A.<b> = C(d, e, f)')
"A = C(d, e, f, names=('b',)); (b,) = A._first_ngens(1)"
```

Comment: The author of this grammar (I don't mean the author of this answer) needs exorcism.

Comment: This grammar was inspired by the Magma user language. The preparser hack is nasty, but I don't see what's bad in the grammar per se.

Comment: This - the preparser hack is nasty.

Comment: Well, depends on what you mean by nasty.  In this case, the desire to have something users would instantly be familiar with overrode nasty.